Is it okay to explain Projective line with lines through origin in $\mathbb R^2$?
I want to start with definitions. Affine space $\mathbb A^n$ over the field $K$ is the set of $x_i$'s i.e.,
$\mathbb{A}^n = \{(x_1,\dots,x_n):x_i \in K \}$
if $n=2$, projective line defined to be $\mathbb P^2$ is set containing all lines through the origin in $\mathbb A$. Here, explanation was link, Points of the projective line are the lines through the origin in $\mathbb R^2$.
Why do we get the right to think this over $\mathbb R^2$ even though our entries coming from the field $K$? Of course, if we particularly choose space to be projective real line then I am okay with that. What strange to me is many sources explain sort of classic concept. I mean draw all lines passing through origin and they must meet at $x=1$. They all think the concept on $\mathbb R$, what about any field $K$. I can't even imagine how can I draw lines through the origin in arbitrary field $K$?

Concerning lines for arbitrary $K$ see this post, for example.

Even if you can't imagine drawing the line, the concept of a line still makes sense very naturally. Hilbert's quote: "One must be able to say at all times--instead of points, straight lines, and planes--tables, chairs, and beer mugs". We have a good drawing model in the case of real field, and it helps our intuition for more cases.

You should think of the picture of the real case an analogy. Some of the properties go across the analogy (eg two distinct lines through the origin determine a unique plane containing both) and some of them might not (eg each plane through the origin contains infinitely many lines through the origin over $\mathbf{R}$ but not over a finite $K$). Knowing whether some specific fact can be checked by analogy requires experience.
If your definition of the projective plane (space) is the set of lines through the origin then a reasonable definition of a projective line that does not require this analogy is (the set of lines contained in) a plane through the origin. But the reason it's called a line is ultimately because of the analogy.
To be precise, by a line (resp. plane) in $K^n$ or $\mathbb{A}^n(K)$ I mean a $1$-dimensional (resp. $2$-dimensional) linear/affine subspace, ie one cut out by $n - 1$ (resp. $n - 2$) independent linear equations.
